# Ошибка Fatal error: Allowed memory size of xxx bytes exhausted

Tags: php

в данном коде вылезафет такая ошибка Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 36 bytes) в чем дело?

```
$partYes = [];
$partNo = [];
$i = 0;
while($i <=100){
    if($i % 3 == 0){
        $partYes[] = $i;
    }else{
        $partNo[] = $i;
    }
} $i++;

echo "Делятся на 3: ";
foreach($partYes as $value1){
    echo $value1;
}
echo "НЕ делятся на 3: ";
foreach($partNo as $value2){
    echo $value2;
}
```

Comment: куда интересней, по-моему, почему выделялось именно 36 байт, ведь в массив добавляется только одно число, которое явно не 36 байт занимает :) Какие операции пхп проводит при добавлении числа в массив.

Comment: можно было бы предположить, что память выделяется блоком, но 36байт как то мало для такого блока.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас `$i++;` из цикла выпало, и он бесконечно крутится, пока память не кончается.
Попробуйте так:

```
while($i <=100){
    if($i % 3 == 0){
        $partYes[] = $i;
    }else{
        $partNo[] = $i;
    } 
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Инкремент выпало решил))

```
<?php

$partYes = [];
$partNo = [];
$i = 0;
while($i <=100){
    if($i % 3 == 0){
        $partYes[] = $i;
    }else{
        $partNo[] = $i;
    }$i++;
} 

echo "Делятся на 3:<br/> ";
foreach($partYes as $value1){
    echo "$value1 ";
}
echo "<br/>НЕ делятся на 3:<br/> ";
foreach($partNo as $value2){
    echo "$value2 ";
}



?>
```